# I am trying to run a remove function for inputed files however nothing is working

Tags: javascript, html, dom, removechild

I am currently making the front end of my NFT Marketplace and I am creating the functionality for my minting page. I created an update file element that allows users to upload an image into the box container and added a close button just in case they change their mind and want to upload another image. The function does remove the image, however, it removes the element as a whole and now no image can be uploaded period. I do not know what is going on with my code and it's probably something super simple, but I have not been able to find a solution yet. Here is my code. I know CSS, Javascript, and HTML are supposed to be in different files but I put them together for now because there is not too much code. Also, stack overflow is not letting me run a snippet I do not know what's going on. Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Creating NFT</title>

    <style>
      body {
        background-image:url("");
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        color: black;
        font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
      }

      .Horizons {
        position: relative;
        font-size: 8vw;
        font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        float: left;
        top: 0%;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color:#f0e1e4;
        border-radius: 3%;
      }

      .Horizons:hover {
        color: salmon;
      }

      .MintingIntro {
        position: relative;
        font-size: 1.563rem;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .NftCard {
        border: 0.25rem solid black;
        height: 30rem;
        width: 25rem;
        background-color: white;
        object-fit: contain;
        top: 23%;
        position: absolute;
      }

      @media (max-width:920px){
        .NftCard{
          width: 20rem;
        
        }

        .Customization{
          left:0%;
          top:0%;
        }

        .DescriptionInput{
          width: 15rem;
        }
      }

      .NftUpload {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
      }

      .Upload {
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        left: 32%;
        display: none;
      }

      .Upload:hover {
        color: grey;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      .upload-file {
        text-align:center;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 8%;
        display: block;
        border:transparent;
        width: 8.75rem;
        height: 1.875rem;
        font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 1.375rem;
        border-radius: 0.625rem;
        background-color: lightskyblue;
        margin: 0.313rem;
        padding: 0.375rem;
        cursor: pointer;
        color:white;
      }

      .upload-file:hover {
        background-color:green;
      }

      .Customization {
        position: absolute;
        height: fit-content;
        width: fit-content;
        text-align: center;
        right: 20%;
        top:20%;
      }

      .NameCustom {
        padding-bottom: 5rem;
      }

      .NameIn {
        font-size: 1.88rem;
      }

      .NameInput {
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
        border-radius: 0%;
        font-size: 1.188rem;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        border: 0.13rem solid black;
      }

      .SupplyIn {
        font-size: 1.88rem;
      }

      .SupplyInput {
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
        border-radius: 0%;
        font-size: 1.188rem;
        bottom: 0%;
        position: relative;
        left: 0%;
        border: 0.13rem solid black;
      }

      .SupplyCustom {
        padding-bottom: 5rem;
      }

      .DescriptionIn {
        font-size: 1.88rem;
        position: relative;
        top: 0%;
        z-index: 5;
        right: 0%;
      }

      .DescriptionInput {
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
        border-radius: 0%;
        font-size: 1.063rem;
        bottom: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        position: relative;
        width: 25rem;
        height: 6.25rem;
        border: 0.13rem solid black;
      }

      .close {
        z-index: 5;
        font-size: 1.875rem;
        color: black;
        background-color: transparent;
        border: 0.063rem solid transparent;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0.063rem;
        top: 0.063rem;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      .close:hover {
        color: salmon;
      }

  

    </style>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="background">
    <a
      href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/styles/HorizonsFrontEndTest2.html"
      target="_self"
      class="Horizons"
      >H</a>

    <div class="NftCard">
      <button class="close" id="closeBtn" onclick="closeButton()">
        &times;
      </button>
      <img src="" id="Nft-Image" class="NftUpload" />
      <label class="upload-file" for="input-file">Update File</label>
      <input
        class="Upload"
        type="file"
        accept="img/jpeg, img/png, img/jpg"
        id="input-file"
      />
    </div>
  
    <div class="Customization">
       <div>
      <h1 class="MintingIntro">CREATE NFT</h1>
    </div>
      <div class="NameCustom">
        <label for="Name" class="NameIn" id="Name">Name of your NFT</label>
        <input type="text" class="NameInput" name="Name" />
      </div>
      <div class="SupplyCustom">
        <label for="Supply" class="SupplyIn" id="Supply">Supply</label>
        <input type="text" class="SupplyInput" supply="Supply" />
      </div>
      <div class="DescriptionCustom">
        <label for="Description" class="DescriptionIn" id="Description"
          >Description</label
        >
        <input type="text" class="DescriptionInput" description="Description" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      
      let closeButton = document.querySelector('.close');
      let nftImage = document.querySelector('#Nft-Image');
      let inputFile = document.querySelector('#input-file');

      inputFile.onchange = function (){
        nftImage.src = URL.createObjectURL(inputFile.files[0]);
      };

      closeButton.addEventListener('click', function closeButton(){
        nftImage.remove();
      });
    
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I attempted to change the variables I was using in my function however nothing worked. I tried refreshing my page and again nothing worked. I do not know why. I tried removeChild, removeAttributes, etc too, and still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

> however it removes the element as a whole

That's exactly what this does:

```
nftImage.remove();
```

Elsewhere you are setting a property on the element:

```
nftImage.src = URL.createObjectURL(inputFile.files[0]);
```

It sounds like you just want to reset that property instead:

```
nftImage.src = "";
```

Comment: @EGstacking you can also add `.NftUpload[src=""] { display: none; }` to your css to hide the image placeholder when no image is selected

Comment: Yes it worked!!! Thank you so much. I am now just learning Javascript so I am all over the place at the moment haha. May I ask you something else?

Comment: @EGstacking: You can ask whatever you like.  But aware however that if you're looking to ask about a separate issue in the code then that's likely best done as a separate Stack Overflow question.  Comments are best for short clarifications about the questions/answers and are poorly suited for ongoing conversations.

Comment: Yes of course:) I am definitely going to upload another post however the quick question I have for you is regarding javascript syntax. I see people using all these different keywords and terms and was wondering if people just create some of these terms on their own, or they are already established by the programming language? I am having a bit of a hard time figuring out what keywords I should use in my javascript for the tasks I am trying to do. I don't know if I am making any sense or not.

Comment: @EGstacking: No, people are not making up their own JavaScript keywords.  The JavaScript language is defined and documented.  You may be misunderstanding what a language "keyword" is.

Comment: Yeah I did not use the proper terminology haha. Keywords are predefined. But thank you!